# How to remove all files from Azure File Share?

Tags: azure, azure-cli, fileshare

How to remove all files from Azure File Share? There is no possibility of doing it in GUI also Microsoft Azure File Explorer fails due to proxy between me and the web.

Is there any AZ command or a snippet that clears the given fileshare in Azure?

Comment: Can't you simply delete the share?

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS Did that previously, to fix that in terraform and kubernetes took a lot of time.

Comment: @JoyWang I will be verifying it soon, I've just updated it for the time being. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, any update this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`az storage file delete-batch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/file?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-file-delete-batch), specify the `--pattern` with `*`, then it will delete all the files in the `--source`, in your case, if you want to delete all files from the file share, just specify `--source` with share name.

**Note**:The command just delete the files, except the directorys.

```
az storage file delete-batch --account-key 'xxxx' --account-name 'joystoragev2' --pattern * --source 'share1'
```

Comment: how can we remove all the files and directories recursively?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

1. Mount the file share somewhere

   - if the network settings allow it, click **Connect** and **Show script** to get something you can paste into a terminal to mount the file share.
   - if you can't access the file share via smb, boot up a VM in Azure or an [SSH-enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-linux-open-ssh-session?pivots=container-linux) Webapp in an App Service and [mount the file share into that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?tabs=basic%2Cportal&pivots=container-linux).
2. Run the fastest delete operation available on your OS. On Linux or Mac you can sync an empty folder into your fileshare to quickly delete everything:
   `rsync -a --delete $(mktemp -d)/ /filesharemount/folder/`